# Remove Office 2016 title from PDF

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office

After upgrading from 2013 to 2016 a user brought up this complaint.

Title is set is on Excel file properties to Yada Yada this is transferred over to the title of the PDF.

User wants the title of the PDF to be the same as the file name. If no title in PDF Acrobat Reader displays the file name as a the title.
Manual fix was to remove title from Excel file properties but that's not suitable for 1000s of files.

Is it possible for Excel to not set the title on the PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the options window when publishing as a PDF there is a checkbox to include non-printing information, document properties.  Unchecking that box did what the user was looking for but the setting couldn't be set as default and wasn't remembered.

Office 2016 Administrative templates fix this.
Office 2016\Save As PDF and XPS add-ins\Disable inclusion of document properties in PDF and XPS output set to enabled.

This is likely a unique scenario but I didn't find this fix posted elsewhere. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're asking but a search for my issues brought me here.
When making a PDF from Office. Instead of printing to a PDF, use the **Export option**.
When saving (or **Publishing** as the UI says), click "Options...", then uncheck "**Document properties**".